# Disable/remove the "Best Reply" link inside my discussion board app

Tags: 2013, development, discussion-board, jslink, rating

I have added a new Discussion Board APP inside my team site collection, but i do not want users to mark specific replies as "Best Reply".. so is this possible to remove or hide the "Best Reply" link ?

[image]

Comment: Are you fine with CSS solution?

Comment: @AsadRefai yes any solution which can hide it will be fine as I have access to the SP server on-primise deployment